# How to get a 24 hours format

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Using VB.Net and ASp.net

Code

```
Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
```

Above Code is showing as `20140916050630`  (050630 - is a time and also pm, so i want to display as 170630)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `hh` to `HH` for 24h format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```

The upper-case "H"s define the format as 24-hour.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `hh` with `HH` since `HH` represents 24 hour format

```
Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
```